# Using a variable in symbol form and vector form in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

If `R = [0, 0, 1]`, there are some cases when I would like to use `Symbol('R')` and others when `Matrix([0, 0, 1])` is more useful in equations. How do I pick and choose when to use each form without defining too many variables? 
(e.g. `R = Symbol('R')` and `R_vec = Matrix([0, 0, 1])` is bad)

Answer (score 2):

One way of approaching this problem is to define `R` as a symbol, which you can substitute, via `subs()`, when needed, e.g.:

```
import sympy as sym


R = sym.Symbol('R')
R.subs({'R': sym.Matrix([1, 0, 0])})                                                                                                                    
# Matrix([
# [1],
# [0],
# [0]])
```

---

As per @OscarBenjamin comment, you may possibly prefer a `MatrixSymbol()` over a regular `Symbol()` as it will play more nicely with matrix operations.

Comment: A MatrixSymbol is preferable as it can work when multiplying other matrices e.g. `MatrixSymbol('x', 1, 3) * Matrix([0, 0, 1])`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the suggestions. For my particular project I think it's suitable to store both sides of the equation in a tuple (LHS, RHS) from the get-go and just use each side R[i] when needed. I understand I asked you for how to deal with this in sympy specifically, so thank you for your sympy specific answers

```
R = (Symbol('R'), Matrix([0, 0, 1]))
```